# Strange Azure Service bus behaviour - subscription #2 is receiving message while subscription #1 is not

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am having some very strange issues with Azure Service Bus topic subscriptions. For the reference I have extracted the service bus topic configurations via `service bus explorer` and hoping somebody could point me into the right direction here. Really appreciate any help I can get.

**Setup**

I have 1 topic named `topic2` and two subscription for this topic `topicsub2` and `topicsub3`.

**Issues**

When publishing message to topic. Subscription `topicsub3` recieves all messages that are sent while `topicsub2` does not receive any messages. This behaviour is random, sometimes I would see messages in `topicsub2` and sometimes the message is never delivered to the `topicsub2` both subscriptions are using the same filters.

Followings are the few test scenarios that I have tried to figure out why this is happening.

- I tried removing the `filter` from `topicsub2` and sending message. But this had no impact still no messages. My assumption is that if no filters are applied all message for the topic will be forwarded to the subscription.
- After removing the filter, I added default `SQL filter (1=1)` filter back to the subscription and tried sending message again it didn't work. I tried sending 5 messages to the topic, none of them appeared in the subscription `topicsub2` and all were received by `topicsub3`.
- I restarted the console application receiver (console application that reads from topicsub2) and tried sending messages again. This time it worked.
- After about 10 mins, the subscription `topicsub2` stopped receiving messages again.

**Summary**

This is where I am at. My investigation leads me this behaviour is random and there is some idling going on in `topicsub2` that I am unaware of. `Topicsub3` is working fine.

Can somebody please lead me into the right direction?

Following is the settings for topic 2 including the two subscriptions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entities xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicebusexplorer" serviceBusNamespace="defaultstd">
   <Topics>
      <Topic>
         <DefaultMessageTimeToLive>14.00:00:00</DefaultMessageTimeToLive>
         <AutoDeleteOnIdle>10675199.02:48:05.4775807</AutoDeleteOnIdle>
         <MaxSizeInMegabytes>1024</MaxSizeInMegabytes>
         <RequiresDuplicateDetection>False</RequiresDuplicateDetection>
         <DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow>00:10:00</DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow>
         <Path>topic2</Path>
         <EnableBatchedOperations>True</EnableBatchedOperations>
         <SupportOrdering>False</SupportOrdering>
         <EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing>True</EnableFilteringMessagesBeforePublishing>
         <IsAnonymousAccessible>False</IsAnonymousAccessible>
         <Status>Active</Status>
         <UserMetadata />
         <EnablePartitioning>True</EnablePartitioning>
         <EnableExpress>False</EnableExpress>
         <IsReadOnly>False</IsReadOnly>
         <Subscriptions>
            <Subscription>
               <LockDuration>00:00:30</LockDuration>
               <RequiresSession>False</RequiresSession>
               <DefaultMessageTimeToLive>14.00:00:00</DefaultMessageTimeToLive>
               <AutoDeleteOnIdle>10675199.02:48:05.4775807</AutoDeleteOnIdle>
               <EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration>True</EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration>
               <EnableDeadLetteringOnFilterEvaluationExceptions>True</EnableDeadLetteringOnFilterEvaluationExceptions>
               <TopicPath>topic2</TopicPath>
               <Name>topicsub2</Name>
               <MaxDeliveryCount>2</MaxDeliveryCount>
               <EnableBatchedOperations>False</EnableBatchedOperations>
               <Status>Active</Status>
               <ForwardTo />
               <ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo />
               <UserMetadata />
               <IsReadOnly>False</IsReadOnly>
               <Rules>
                  <Rule>
                     <Filter>
                        <SqlFilter>
                           <SqlExpression>sys.Label NOT IN  ('TestEvent')</SqlExpression>
                           <CompatibilityLevel>20</CompatibilityLevel>
                        </SqlFilter>
                     </Filter>
                     <Action>
                        <EmptyRuleAction />
                     </Action>
                     <Name>$Default</Name>
                     <IsReadOnly>True</IsReadOnly>
                  </Rule>
               </Rules>
            </Subscription>
            <Subscription>
               <LockDuration>00:00:30</LockDuration>
               <RequiresSession>False</RequiresSession>
               <DefaultMessageTimeToLive>14.00:00:00</DefaultMessageTimeToLive>
               <AutoDeleteOnIdle>10675199.02:48:05.4775807</AutoDeleteOnIdle>
               <EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration>True</EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration>
               <EnableDeadLetteringOnFilterEvaluationExceptions>True</EnableDeadLetteringOnFilterEvaluationExceptions>
               <TopicPath>topic2</TopicPath>
               <Name>topicsub3</Name>
               <MaxDeliveryCount>2</MaxDeliveryCount>
               <EnableBatchedOperations>False</EnableBatchedOperations>
               <Status>Active</Status>
               <ForwardTo />
               <ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo />
               <UserMetadata />
               <IsReadOnly>False</IsReadOnly>
               <Rules>
                  <Rule>
                     <Filter>
                        <SqlFilter>
                           <SqlExpression>sys.Label NOT IN  ('TestEvent')</SqlExpression>
                           <CompatibilityLevel>20</CompatibilityLevel>
                        </SqlFilter>
                     </Filter>
                     <Action>
                        <EmptyRuleAction />
                     </Action>
                     <Name>$Default</Name>
                     <IsReadOnly>True</IsReadOnly>
                  </Rule>
               </Rules>
            </Subscription>
         </Subscriptions>
      </Topic>
   </Topics>
</Entities>
```

Comment: If you set SQL filter to `1=1`, all messages sent to `topic2` should be received by both subscriptions. If that's not the case, something's off with the subscriptions. In that case, you can either open a support case with MSFT or re-create your entities.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I disabled and re-enabled the topic. The 2nd subscription started getting messages. But I am little worried now whether same issue will occur in production and I would have to manually disable enable topic's. The interesting thing is that, the TopicClient doesn't throw any exceptions, the problem seems to be at azure broker end. Have you had any issues like this in your time using Azure service bus? What are the common issues you have faced? I will open a ticket for Microsoft for sure.

Comment: I haven't had an issue like this. That's why I recommend project to talk to MSFT support first, so that they can troubleshoot on the broker side.